# CS1501 C# No overload for method takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, .net

Estou começando a me aventurar no C#, porém estou obtendo o erro

> "CS1501  C# No overload for method takes 2 arguments"

O código é muito simples e provavelmente não contém erro, pois estou usando o código disponibilizado (via download) pelo autor do livro que estou seguindo, conforme abaixo.

Código:

```
namespace ClassDemo  
{  
    class Staff  
    {  
        private string nameOfStaff;  
        private const int hourlyRate = 30;  
        private int hWorked;  
        public int HoursWorked  
        {  
            get  
            {  
                return hWorked;  
            }  
            set  
            {
                if (value > 0)
                    hWorked = value;
                else
                    hWorked = 0;
            }
        }

        public void PrintMessage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calculating Pay...");
        }

        public int CalculatePay()
        {
           PrintMessage();

            int staffPay;
            staffPay = hWorked * hourlyRate;

            if (hWorked > 0)
                return staffPay;
            else
                return 0;
        }

        public int CalculatePay(int bonus, int allowance)
        {
            PrintMessage();

            if (hWorked > 0)
                return hWorked * hourlyRate + bonus + allowance;
            else
                return 0;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Name of Staff = " + nameOfStaff + ", hourlyRate = " + hourlyRate + ", hWorked = " + hWorked;
        }

        public Staff(string name)
        {
            nameOfStaff = name;
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + nameOfStaff);
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
        }

        public Staff(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            nameOfStaff = firstName + " " + lastName;
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + nameOfStaff);
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int pay;

            Staff staff1 = new Staff("Peter");
            staff1.HoursWorked = 160;
            pay = staff1.CalculatePay(1000, 400);
            Console.WriteLine("Pay = {0}", pay);

            Staff staff2 = new Staff("Jane", "Lee");
            staff2.HoursWorked = 160;
            pay = staff2.CalculatePay();
            Console.WriteLine("Pay = {0}", pay);

            Staff staff3 = new Staff("Carol");
            staff3.HoursWorked = -10;
            pay = staff3.CalculatePay();
            Console.WriteLine("Pay = {0}", pay);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Resolveu o problema?

Answer (score 1):

O código não compila porque falta um `using System` no começo. Mas não dá o erro informado. Resolvendo o problema citado ele [compila e executa normalmente no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/josRn6).